# RDS Aurora Proxy connection fails with "Failed to Connect to MySQL"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, amazon-rds-proxy

So basically - I've enabled RDS Proxy (still in Preview) for my Aurora MySQL DB and the Proxy is created and available for use.

1. The Proxy uses a DB User/Pwd combination sourced from Secrets
   Manager to connect to the MySQL DB.
2. The Proxy can be accessed without Authentication (IAM role based
   authentication is supported but I've not configured it yet).

When I connect to the proxy endpoint it fails with "*Failed to Connect to MySQL*" on my MySQL client and on the Cloudwatch logs for the Proxy I see the following 2 lines for each connection attempt..

> [INFO] [clientConnection=3488645722] New client connection from 10.XX.XX.XX:63344
>   [INFO] [clientConnection=3488645722] Client connection closed. Reason: Internal error.

Cloudwatch Metrics just reports increase in **ClientConnectionsReceived** metric for each connection attempt and no change to the **ClientConnectionsClosed** metric.

So basically I am clueless as to why the client connection is getting closed.. Any hints/clues would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Try one of those:

1. Ensure your user is created in the RDS Database. Test that you able to connect directly with that user.
2. Ensure RDS proxy security group is whitelisted in the RDS security group.
3. On the secrets manager ensure you've selected the right RDS database.